# Elasticsearch lowercase tokenizer quirk?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I am testing mapping for url-s in elasticsearch.

I want to be able to search for entry both by domain name with tld (e.g. `example.com`)
and without tld (e.g `example`) and for full domain document to be returned
(like, `http://example.com` and `www.example.com` and similar)

I PUT this mapping to ES - in Sense:

```
PUT /en_docs
    { 
   "mappings": {
      "url": {
        "properties": {
          "content": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer" : "urlzer"
          }
        }
      }
    },

    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "urlzer": {
                  "type": "custom",
                  "tokenizer": "lowercase",
                  "filter": [ "stopwords_filter" ]
                }

            },
            "filter" : {
              "stopwords_filter" : {
                "type" : "stop",
                "stopwords" : ["http", "https", "ftp", "www"]
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I index an url document, e.g

```
POST /en_docs/url
{
"content":  "http://example.com"
}
```

I can get it by searching `example.com` but just `example` doesnt return anything.
The `lowercase` tokenizer im using in my analyzer, as docs say, and as direct testing of my analyzer shows, gives `example` and `com` tokens, but when I do the search for indexed document, `example` returns nothing:

```
GET /en_docs/url/_search?q=example
```

gets no results, but if the query is `example.com`, result is returned.

What am I missing?

Comment: How does the query look ? This works for me.
Below is the example gist: https://www.found.no/play/gist/31fb88c9789e14d60df4#

Comment: @toninoj, what query are you using for searching?

Comment: I edited my question with the search query & endpoints for other requests.